# Android Studio kotlin . How to make DatabaseModule to change databse immediately after language change of App

Tags: android, database, kotlin, dagger-hilt

when I change the language , app lang is changing immediately but Database is changing after relaunch how to make it change immediately

Since language is being changed I am assuming all good with rest of my codes?
but not sure where to change to apply database to change right away

```
package com.hfad.ismlarmanosi2023.data

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Room
import com.hfad.ismlarmanosi2023.language.MyPreference
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import javax.inject.Singleton

> @Module
> @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DatabaseModule {

>     @Singleton
>     @Provides
fun provideDatabase(
>         @ApplicationContext context: Context,
myPreference: MyPreference,
NamesDatabase {
val lang = myPreference.getLoginCount()
val databaseFileName = if (lang == "en") "all_names.db" else "all_names_uz.db"

return Room.databaseBuilder(
context,
NamesDatabase::class.java,
databaseFileName
>         ).createFromAsset("databases/$databaseFileName").build()
>     }

>     @Singleton
>     @Provides
fun provideDao(database: NamesDatabase) = database.namesDao()

>     @Singleton
>     @Provides
fun provideContext(@ApplicationContext context: Context): Context {
return context
>     }

> }
```